# Enable Debug mode at build time using Grunt

Tags: build, gruntjs

I would like to mock some services of a client side web application when I am during development and use proper services when in production.

It would be great if I could do this at build time by passing grunt a flag or something that I could then use in the code to know what endpoints to use.

My idea is to do something like this:
`if (DEBUG) {
service = MOCK_SERVICE; } else { service = SERVICE; }`
and set this `DEBUG` flag at build.

If there is a solution for this or even a better alternative, I would much appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `grunt.option`:

```
var DEBUG = !!grunt.option('dbug');
```

Then you can enable that option any time with `grunt --dbug`. The option could be named anything though: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option

Grunt internally uses an option named `debug` which you could use as well but it will make your output more verbose so just be aware of that.